# For loop not working as expected

Tags: python

A basic nest for loop that looks like this:

```
test = [
    "AAAAAAAAAAA",
    "BBBBBBBBBBB",
    "CCCCCCCCCCC",
]
for row in test:
    for col in row:
        print col
```

Should output every single character within the `test` list. However, I am running this exact same thing in one of my games for level design and it stops after the first row.

```
for row in level:
        for col in row:
            print col
            if col == "G":
                g = Grass(x,y)
                obsticles.append(g)
                entities.add(g)
                print "grass added to entites"
            elif col == "P":
                p = Plain_Grass(x,y)
                obsticles.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            elif col == "F":
                f = Grass_Flower(x,y)
                obsticles.append(f)
                entities.add(f)
            elif col == "Y":
                y = Grass_To_SandD(x,y)
                obsticles.append(y)
                entities.add(y)
```

I honestly do not understand why. I know this is probably the most newbiest question I have ever asked but it is honestly annoying me. I have tried this with the exact same `test` and everything. I have created another program to see if it works when not in the game program and it does. Can anyone see the problem?

[EDIT] Here is my tilemap file:

```
def testPlace():

    #This is where all the testing happens...

    tilemap = [
        # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
        "T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T T",
        "T G F G G G G P P F P G G G G G G G G T",
        "T G G G G G G G F G P G G G G G G G G G",
        "T G G G G G G G G F P F F G F G G G G G",
        "O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O",
        "O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O",
        "G G F G G G G G G O O F G G G G G G G G",
        "F G F T G G G G T O O F G G G G G G G G",
        "T G G G G G G G G O O T G G G G F G P G",
        "G G G T F G G G G O O G G G G G G G T G",
        "G G G G G G G G G G G G G F G G G T G G",
        "Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y",
        "S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S",
        "S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S",
        "S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S S",
        "Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q Q",
        "W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W",
        "W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W",
        "W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W",
        "W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W",
        "W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W W",
        ]

    return tilemap
```

And the main script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygame, sys, os, tilemap
from pygame.locals import *

#Always ensure that the height and width are devisible by 32!
windowSize = windowWidth, windowHeight = 576, 576
#Ensuring width and height can take 32x32 blocks
if windowWidth%32 == 0 and windowHeight%32 == 0:
    blocksInX = windowWidth/32
    blocksInY = windowHeight/32
else:
    raise SystemExit, "Too Much Space To Fit 32x32 Blocks in X and Y"

#Frames Per Second (MAX, not what it is going to be)
FPS = 15



#Colours
black = [ 0, 0, 0]
white = [255, 255, 255]
red = [255, 0, 0]
green = [ 0, 255, 0]
blue = [ 0, 0, 255]
orange = [ 255, 122, 0]
cyan = [ 0, 155, 255]
purple = [ 155, 0, 255]
lime = [155, 255, 0]

def main():
    #Setting initial variables
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Unnamed Game")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #Defaulting the all controlls to "off" upon first starting (no button is being pushed)
    up = down = left = right = False

    #Assuming everything including player is an entity (including the grass)
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 32)
    obsticles = []

    x = y = 0
    #See tilemaps file for information on the map layout
    level = tilemap.testPlace()
    print level

    #Placing all the blocks needed to be displayed
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            print col
            if col == "G":
                g = Grass(x,y)
                obsticles.append(g)
                entities.add(g)
                print "grass added to entites"
            elif col == "P":
                p = Plain_Grass(x,y)
                obsticles.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            elif col == "F":
                f = Grass_Flower(x,y)
                obsticles.append(f)
                entities.add(f)
            elif col == "Y":
                y = Grass_To_SandD(x,y)
                obsticles.append(y)
                entities.add(y)
            x += 32
        y+= 32
        x = 0

        entities.add(player)

        while True:
            clock.tick(FPS)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                if event.type ==  KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                    #Passing commands for keydown events
                    #UP = "-", down = "+", Left = "-", right = "+"
                    elif event.key == K_UP:
                        up = True
                        print ("UP")
                    elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                        down = True
                        print ("Down")
                    elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                        left = True
                        print ("LEFT")
                    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        right = True
                        print ("RIGHT")

                if event.type == KEYUP:
                    if event.key == K_UP:
                        up = False
                    elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                        down = False
                    elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                        left = False
                    elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        right = False


            #Redrawing the player onto the screen
            player.update(up, down, left, right, obsticles)
            #Redrawing all other objects
            entities.draw(screen)

            pygame.display.update()

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xPos = x
        self.yPos = y
        self.inShop = False
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(red)
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(self.xPos, self.yPos, 32, 32)

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, obsticles):
        if up:
            self.yPos -= 32
        if down:
            self.yPos += 32
        if left:
            self.xPos -= 32
        if right:
            self.xPos += 32

        self.rect = Rect(self.xPos, self.yPos, 32, 32)
        #Collision Detection (for x axis)
        self.collide(self.xPos, 0, obsticles)
        #Collision Detection (for y axis)
        self.collide(0, self.yPos, obsticles)

    def collide(self, xPos, yPos, obsticles):
        pass

class Grass(Entity):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("data/images/Grass.png")
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

class Plain_Grass(Entity):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("data/images/Grass_Plain.png")
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Grass_Flower(Entity):

        def __init__(self, x, y):
                Entity.__init__(self)
                self.image = pygame.image.load("data/images/Grass_Flower.png")
                self.image.convert()
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Grass_To_SandD(Entity):

        def __init__(self, x, y):
                Entity.__init__(self)
                self.image = pygame.image.load("data/images/Grass_To_SandD.png")
                self.image.convert()
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Maybe there is just one row?

Comment: Can you show the value of `level`?

Comment: Any `break` statement in your code?  Currently I see no reason, so I guess you have to tell us more.

Comment: At least your indentation above in the code is inconsistent.

Comment: @Louis I have taken the value of level as shown in the example, and it still cuts off after the "A"'s have finished.

Comment: @Dahaka There isn't just one row.

Comment: Are you trying to find your X,Y coordinates from the row/col? I think I'm going to join the chorus of other posts and request more context....

Comment: It works for me with the sample array you are giving: http://ideone.com/tXohih Are you sure you tested it with those exact pieces of code (both for the array initialization and the loops)?

Comment: @Racso I added my whole program

Comment: I think your problem is at `level = tilemap.testPlace()`

Comment: @Dan No, I am able to see the level and it is what is expected

Comment: Are you getting any execution error?

Comment: @Racso Not that I am aware of

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie You should be getting a NameError that tilemap is not defined on that line. Think about it, since testPlace() returns tilemap, and it is not a class, but a function, how can you call `level = tilemap.testPlace()`?

Comment: Instead use `level = testPlace()`

Comment: @Dan tilemap is another python file for those who were wondering

Comment: Have you checked all your code for an accidental mis-use of tab stops and spaces in a mix, so that things that look like they are indented actually are not?  Python interprets tab stops as as many spaces as it takes to get to the next column which is dividable by 8.  If your editor displays them differently, that could render a block which looks indented actually unindented.

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie that makes more sense, but was not clarified in the code you posted

Comment: I again tried out your posted code (stripped it off all the pygame stuff not involved in the issue) and still could not reproduce your problem.  I'm suspecting a ghost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my shot:

You have all the code after `entities.add(player)` indented INSIDE the loop. Remove the extra indentation to put it outside the loop.

EDIT:
In fact, I guess the `entities.add(player)` should be out of the loop, too.

Comment: How could that abort the outer loop prematurely??

Comment: I didn't think that this could end the loop but apparently it can. I was actually using notepad++ for some of the code and didn't realise the tab settings were set to "8". I constantly switched between idle and notepad++ so my indentation was out. Thankyou!

Comment: It is not, but it's executing all the game logic just after reading the first line of the array. It's running the game while reading the world data!

Comment: Ahh … :-)) So there is no abortion at all, just a sidekick which does not terminate.